# Having issues in Python reading GPIO input pins while using Tkinter buttons

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying to read GPIO pins as input while using Tkinter as a graphics module to also control outputs. So far it's not proving well. I've overcome the looping issue getting around the "while True" argument replacing it with an after but sleep issues are locking up the program. I don't know python well enough to know the proper syntax for .after for a delay. I think using a global might help but I'm not sure how to write it in Python. I'm more of a C, C# and C++ developer and I'm relatively new to Python. So I'll post my code so far and if anyone has any ideas, I'm surely listening!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from random import randint
from tkinter import Tk, Button, NSEW
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from signal import pause

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("ARBOR 4.0")
myFont = tkinter.font.Font(family = 'Helvectica', size = 24, weight = "bold")

Relay1 = LED(5) #Left Bin Selection
Relay2 = LED(6) #Right Bin Selection
Relay3 = LED(13) #Latch Release
Relay4 = LED(12) #General Bin Selection Signal
LimitSW = Button(26) #Sense Status of Door
SensePin = Button(16) #3.3V Return for System Use Status
SprinklerSense = Button(14) #Sprinkler sense
FireSense = Button(19) #Fire sense circuit

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#  GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) Perhaps Broadcom is problem
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
POLLING_DELAY = 3000

def get_gpio_input():
    return randint(1, 10) < 3

def check_status():
    input_state1 = GPIO.input(26)
    input_state2 = GPIO.input(16)
    input_state3 = GPIO.input(14)
    input_state4 = GPIO.input(19)
    if input_state1 == True:
        if input_state2 == True:
            LimitSW["text"] = "System In Use"
    else if input_state3 == True;
        LimitSW["text"] = "System Cleaning, Please Wait!"
    win.after(1)
    else if input_state4 == True;
       LimitSW["text"] = "Fire Alert! Please Wait!" bg='red'
    else:
        LimitSW["text"] = "System Available"
        Relay1.off()
        Relay2.off()
        Relay3.off()
        Relay4.off() # Reset all relays to off

def selectOption1():
    if Relay1.is_lit:
        Relay1.off()
        paperButton["text"] = "Paper"
    else:
        if LimitSW["text"] == "System Available":
            Relay1.on() # Signal Left Bin Selection
            Relay3.on() # Open Latch
            LimitSW["text"] = "System In Use"
            paperButton["text"] = "Please Wait!"
            win.after(1000)
            Relay1.off() # Signal Left Bin Selection
            Relay3.off() # Open Latch
            paperButton["text"] = "Paper"
            LimitSW["text"] = "System Available"

def selectOption2():
    if Relay2.is_lit:
        Relay1.off()
        plasticButton["text"] = "Plastic"
    else:
        if LimitSW["text"] == "System Available":
            Relay2.on() # Signal Right Bin Selection
            Relay3.on() # Open Latch
            LimitSW["text"] = "System In Use"
            plasticButton["text"] = "Please Wait!"
            win.after(1000)
            Relay2.off() # Signal Left Bin Selection
            Relay3.off() # Open Latch
            plasticButton["text"] = "Plastic"
            LimitSW["text"] = "System Available"

def selectOption3():
    if Relay2.is_lit:
        Relay2.off()
        glassButton["text"] = "Glass/Metal"
    else:
        if LimitSW["text"] == "System Available":
            Relay2.on() # Signal Right Bin Selection
            Relay3.on() # Open Latch
            LimitSW["text"] = "System In Use"
            glassButton["text"] = "Pleae Wait!"
            win.after(1000)
            Relay2.off() # Signal Left Bin Selection
            Relay3.off() # Open Latch
            glassButton["text"] = "Glass/Metal"
            LimitSW["text"] = "System Available"

def selectOption4():
    if Relay4.is_lit:
        Relay3.off()
        Relay4.off()
        generalButton["text"] = "General Waste"
    else:
        if LimitSW["text"] == "System Available":
            Relay4.on() # Signal Home Bin Selection
            Relay3.on() # Open Latch
            LimitSW["text"] = "System In Use"
            generalButton["text"] = "Pleae Wait!"
            win.after(1000)
            Relay4.off() # Signal Left Bin Selection
            Relay3.off() # Open Latch
            generalButton["text"] = "General Waste"
            LimitSW["text"] = "System Available"

def exitProgram():
    win.quit()
    win.destroy()

LimitSW=tk.Button(win, text='System Available', font=myFont, bg='orange', height=2, width=36)
LimitSW.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

paperButton=tk.Button(win, text='Paper', font=myFont, command=selectOption1, bg='blue', height=2, width=36)
paperButton.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.NSEW)

plasticButton=tk.Button(win, text='Plastic', font=myFont, command=selectOption2, bg='red', height=2, width=36)
plasticButton.grid(row=2, sticky=tk.NSEW)

glassButton=tk.Button(win, text='Glass/Metal', font=myFont, command=selectOption3, bg='green', height=2, width=36)
glassButton.grid(row=3, sticky=tk.NSEW)

generalButton=tk.Button(win, text='General Waste', font=myFont, command=selectOption4, bg='purple', height=2, width=36)
generalButton.grid(row=4, sticky=tk.NSEW)

exitButton=tk.Button(win, text='Exit', font=myFont, command=exitProgram, bg='purple', height=2, width=36)
exitButton.grid(row=5, sticky=tk.NSEW)

win.after(0, check_status)
win.mainloop()
```

It's a recycling interface and I'm really needing help if anyone is up to the task. This is running on a Raspberry Pi using a 5" touch screen. Thanks in advance if anyone has any advice for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a thread in an infinite while loop that checks the status of a pin (ON/OFF) and performs actions accordingly.
You can also set up an interrupt but it will be a bit complicated and probably overkill. You can refer following code and tweak here and there to match your needs:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import tkinter as tk



class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pi_button()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = lambda: self.say_hi('tk button pressed')
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")


    def pi_button(self):
        #Setup GPIO for input
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
        self.input_state = GPIO.input(18)
        #Check to see if button is pressed, if it is print notification
        if self.input_state == False:
            self.say_hi('rpi button pressed')
        #Use tks main loop as a while loop to call for a check every .5 seconds
        self.after(500, self.pi_button)

    def say_hi(self, text):

        print(text)



root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```